# How to get an oauth accessToken without asking the user to log-in again with Firebase-auth?

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I am using firebase auth for authentication. The `signInWithPopup` returns a `UserCredentials` object from which I can get an `accessToken`, allowing me to make API calls on behalf of the user:

```js
const url = new URL(`https://www.googleapis.com/whatever`);

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('authorization', `Bearer ${userCredentials.accessToken}`);
headers.append('accept', 'application/json');

const response = await fetch(url, {headers});
```

To avoid asking the user to login every time they load the page, I want to use Firebase's `Authentication State Persistence`:

```js
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
  // whatever...
});
```

But the onAuthStateChanged callback only provides a `User` object, not a `UserCredentials` object. I've been unable to figure out how to get an oauth accessToken from that.

**edit for more details**:
I am using firebase-auth with GoogleAuthProvider in [popup mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#popup-mode) to connect to the [youtube data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at refresh tokens?
[https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#:~:text=Firebase%20ID%20tokens%20are%20short,The%20user%20is%20disabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#:%7E:text=Firebase%20ID%20tokens%20are%20short,The%20user%20is%20disabled)

Refresh tokens are OAuth's way of allowing your app to get a fresh new access/id token without having the user re-authenticate.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to move forward from there... The doc you linked to is for firebase admin, and only discusses refresh tokens revocation. How would you generate an accessToken from the user's refreshtoken ? BTW, the documentation on the refreshtoken property tells me to "Avoid using this directly and prefer User.getIdToken to refresh the ID token instead.", but I don't think an idToken is what I need here.

Comment: The basic idea from OAuth is you get an access token and a refresh token after the user authenticates and authorizes your access. When the access token expires, you make a request to the authorization server with that refresh token and it gives you a fresh access token and optionally another refresh token (depending on their policy). I can't point you to specific docs relevant to what you're doing if you don't share what docs or anything you're working from.

Comment: Sorry, I removed these details from my question because I thought they were irrelevant. I'll edit my question to add them. I am using firebase-auth with GoogleAuthProvider in [popup mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#popup-mode) to connect to the [youtube data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

Comment: This seems to be what you're looking for:
"... Google returns a token to your application. Depending on your application's type, it either validates the token or exchanges it for a different type of token.

For example, a server-side web application exchanges the returned token for an access token and a refresh token. The access token lets the application authorize requests on the user's behalf, and the refresh token lets the application retrieve a new access token when the original access token expires."
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication